# pyautogui doesn't work for keyboard input when Windows is locked

Tags: python, pyautogui, rpa

pyautogui doesn't work for keyboard input when Windows is locked.
raise FailSafeException(
pyautogui.FailSafeException: PyAutoGUI fail-safe triggered from mouse moving to a corner of the screen. To disable this fail-safe, set pyautogui.FAILSAFE to False. DISABLING FAIL-SAFE IS NOT RECOMMENDED.

Is there any method to make pyautogui take keyboard input when windows is locked? Or are there any modules and functions that can do the same?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.